# How to get value of a list item that is generated automatically on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am populating an unordered list item with javascript as follows:

```
for(var i = 0; i < ourData.length; i++){
    $('#searchTeamResultView').append(`<li> <Button class="ui-btn" value=${ourData[i]}> ${ourData[i]["team_long_name"]} </Button> </li>`) 
}
```

The ourData is an array of json objects. I want to get log the value of whatever the button user clicks. I am detecting the click using the following code

```
$("#searchTeamResultView").on("click", "li", function(){
    console.log("FML");  // I don't understand what to put inside the log
})
```

I am unsure on how to log the value of list item on which the user clicks. It would be great if someone could assist me with it. Sorry if this is a noob question. I was unable to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach the event handler to the `button` element instead of the `li`, which makes more sense semantically, then you can simply use `this.value` within the event handler. Try this:

```js
let ourData = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor'];

for (var i = 0; i < ourData.length; i++) {
  $('#searchTeamResultView').append(`<li><button class="ui-btn" value="${ourData[i]}">${ourData[i]}</button></li>`);
}

$("#searchTeamResultView").on("click", "button", function() {
  console.log(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="searchTeamResultView"></ul>
```

Comment: Your solution works. But for some reason, only a part of ourData[i] is logging. The full element in ourData[i] is supposed to be {"_id":49115,"id":49115,"team_api_id":9956,"team_fifa_api_id":322,"team_long_name":"Grasshopper Club Zürich","team_short_name":"GRA"} but it is only logging {"_id":24273,"id":24273,"team_api_id":9876,"team_fifa_api_id":206,"team_long_name":"Hellas . I don't understand why that is happening.

Comment: I changed it for the example as you didn't include any of the `ourData` content. You need to change the text output of the button back to `${ourData[i]["team_long_name"]`

Comment: I already changed that. The problem I wrote in comments was related to something else. I figured that issue out.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once added onclick event, you can get exact element by "this" value.
For example.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  let $elementsDiv = $('.elements');
  
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      //Creating new div with on click handler and adding attr subIndex
      let $newOnclickElement = $('<div></div>')
        .on('click', function() {
            handleOnClick(this);
        })
        .attr('subIndex', i)
        .html('element ' + i);
        
        $elementsDiv.append($newOnclickElement);
  }
});

function handleOnClick(subElement) {
    console.log(subElement);
    //To get its attr for example some new index we gonna add;
    let $subElemenet = $(subElement);
    //Console log subIndex
    console.log($subElemenet.attr('subIndex'));

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='elements'>


</div>
```

Someone beat me to it :(